# Register in Android and mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-webservice

I want to register users in android application using web service in mysql database.
I am using below code in php side:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
require_once("dbconnect.php");
require_once 'jdf.php';

if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Request must be in POST method!');
}
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Request must send in json format!');
}
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$decoded = json_decode($content, true);
if(!is_array($decoded)){
    throw new Exception('invalid request!');
}
$res = $decoded;
$data = array();

if(array_key_exists('username',$res)){
    //username exist
    $username = $res['username'];
    $pass = md5($res['password']);
    $mobile = $res['mobile'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :a");
    $stmt->bindparam(':a',$username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $c = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($c == 0){
        $date = jdate("Y/m/d H:i",'','','','en');
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (mobile, username,  password, reg_date)VALUES(:a, :b, :c, :d)");
        $stmt->bindparam(':a',$mobile);
        $stmt->bindparam(':b',$username);
        $stmt->bindparam(':c',$pass);
        $stmt->bindparam(':d',$date);
        $stmt->execute();
        $s = false;
        $m = 'register successful!';
    }else{
        $s = true;
        $m = 'this user already registered!';
        $res_u = $stmt->fetch();
        $username = $res_u['username'];
        $date = $res_u['reg_date'];
        $data = array('username' => $username, 'date' => $date);
    }
}else{
    $s = true;
    $m = 'username is not sent!';
}

$back = array('error' => $s, 'message' => $m, 'data' => $data);
$json_response = json_encode($back);
echo $json_response;
```

bu in android I am new and just found a sample code in link below:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial/

I'm using exactly codes in this page so I'm not placing them all here, just in register activity I have this code:

```
package ir.sample.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class activity_reg extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txtUser, txtMobile, txtPass;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //if the user is already logged in we will directly start the profile activity
        if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, activity_dashboard.class));
            return;
        }

        txtUser = findViewById(R.id.txt_user);
        txtMobile = findViewById(R.id.txt_mobile);
        txtPass = findViewById(R.id.txt_pass);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_reg).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btn_open_log).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(activity_reg.this, activity_login.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String username = txtUser.getText().toString().trim();
        final String mobile = txtMobile.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = txtPass.getText().toString().trim();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username)){
            txtUser.setError("Enter username!");
            txtUser.requestFocus();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile)){
            txtMobile.setError("Enter mobile!");
            txtMobile.requestFocus();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            txtPass.setError("Enter password!");
            txtPass.requestFocus();
        }

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                try {
                    //converting response to json object
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    //if no error in response
                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //getting the user from the response
                        JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                        //creating a new user object
                        User user = new User(
                        userJson.getInt("id"),
                        userJson.getString("username"),
                        userJson.getString("mobile")
                        );

                        //storing the user in shared preferences
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                        //starting the profile activity
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity_dashboard.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("mobile",mobile);
                params.put("password",password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }


}
```

I have already test my php side with Fiddler and it works well (just as exception), but when I run application and click on register button nothing happens and not working at all nether no errors shown. I want to know how to find errors in this codes because I know that there will a way to print and show errors just like what I do in php (I am good at php).
(sorry if my English is bad)

**UPDATE 1**

after printing exception errors in a toast I received this error:

```
"Value <br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject"
```

I googled it and someone in here posted this for solution:

```
int jsonStart = response.indexOf("{");
                    int jsonEnd = response.lastIndexOf("}");

                    if (jsonStart >= 0 && jsonEnd >= 0 && jsonEnd > jsonStart) {
                        response = response.substring(jsonStart, jsonEnd + 1);
                    }
```

I used the above code and then received this one:

```
"expected ' ' after main at character 6 of {main}"
```

any solution for this problem?

Notice! In server side I have tested it with Fiddler and register was successful also the returned code was in right json format without any HTML code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have printed error in a Toast (the only way I know) and I see this error: "Value <br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject" . Can you tell me what is this error and how to fix it?

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Check the servers error log to see if you get any errors in your PHP code (which would return text or HTML instead of json).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have checked server side with Fiddle (sending test json API). but there is no error in there and just returns what I expected.

Comment: So you can register a user on your actual server using Fiddle (by doing a HTTP request) or have you tested your server code on Fiddle? If it is the first, then it must be your Android code. If it is the second, then you need to check for errors on the _server_, since you can't assume that Fiddle and your server has identical set ups.

Comment: I do register with Fiddle and it was successful. I know that the error is in android code and after printing the exceptions I receive this error: "Value <br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject", I also used a solution for this and then I received this one: expected ' ' after main at character 6 of {main}